# Switch/Change Background Image of CSS in Jquery using if/else

Tags: jquery, image, if-statement

Been at it for hours
Please help

```
   $("#NewsReel").click(function(){
   if( $(".block_news").css("background","url('/new_skool/images/news_1.jpg')no-repeat"))
   {
   $(".block_news").css("background","url('/new_skool/images/news(2).jpg')no-repeat");
   }
   else
   {
   if( $(".block_news").css("background","url('/new_skool/images/news(2).jpg')no-repeat"))
   {
   $(".block_news").css("background","url('/new_skool/images/news_1.jpg')no-repeat");
   }
   }
   });
```

Thank You

It changes the image once, but then does not fire the second if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the background value is not performed this way. You need to use:

```
if ($('element').css('background') == 'value') {
   ...
}
```

Also, there is is no guarantee that jQuery will not optimise or set the background exactly the way in which you set it. For example it might return the value as:

```
no-repeat url('/new_skool/images/news(2).jpg')
```

It's best to create two CSS classes and just use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to change the background image for example in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh6D5/)

#### HTML

```
<ul id="NewsReel">
    <li class="block_news">news</li>
</ul>​
```

#### CSS

```
li {
   background:url('http://lorempixel.com/25/25/abstract/1/') no-repeat;
}

li.clicked {
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/25/25/abstract/2/') no-repeat;
}
```

#### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$("#NewsReel").click(function() {
    $('.block_news').toggleClass('clicked');
    return false;
});
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Use css classes to style the backgrounds with jQuery `addClass` / `removeClass` / `hasClass`.

Answer (score 2):

This line/test:

```
if( $(".block_news").css("background","url('/new_skool/images/news_1.jpg')no-repeat"))
```

...will ALWAYS return the equivalent of true (it returns a jQuery Object).

Answer (score 1):

In all cases your setting the background. To retrieve the value of the background lose the second parameter in the css method.