# if else condition of css in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote below code to get my output.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('.figure').css("left","702px")) {
    $('.level1').css("display", "inline-block");
  } else {
    $('.level1').css("display", "none");            
  }
});
```

What I want when my `.figure` is reach to `left` `702px`. I want to show level1 icon. But now `display none` is not applying before `702px`. That is level1 icon showing before reaching to 702px. Anything wrong ? please help. Even i want to add more conditions that is after some for example `left 1500px` of `.figure` then show `level2 icon`. Thanks.

Comment: you have set value, you did not checked it

Comment: Will the `.figure` be `702px` on page load? How does the `.figure` reach "`left: 702px`"?

Comment: And that `if()` is not doing what you think it is

Comment: use if (left== 702){ then your condition}

Comment: I wonder this, `$('.figure').css("left","702px")` , works in `if condition`

Comment: @Madhavan.V i took this reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10043204/5383669 because == was not working for my previous example.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError it will reach on keypress. it will slide to left on press of right arrow key

Comment: @SagarKodte It is mentiond there itself. `$('.figure').css("left","702px")` return jquery object, in turn if condition will always true.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `if statement` is incorrect. This won't work;

```
if ($('.figure').css("left","702px"))
```

You can't check against CSS values the same way that you *set them*. The if statement above will be evaluating "***set left to 702px and check if successful...***", which will almost always be `true`. Try changing it to the following;

```
if ($('.figure').css("left") == "702px")
```

**Update**

Your comment just made me realise - this probably isn't going to work for you anyway. This will apply at **exactly** 702px **only**. Anything under or over will evaluate false. In that case, try comparing against the offset (this way, you can use < and > which won't work when the value contains 'px' as it does with .css);

```
if ($('.figure').offset().left > 702)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but display Inline block is not applying after 702px

Comment: Shouldn't your left value, you are checking against, be an integer instead of a string, Lewis?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks, fixed =)

Comment: @SagarKodte Refer to the above update and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.figure').css("left","702px")
```

This is used for setting the css value. Inside `if` condition, you need to do a check to match for value.

You can modify the condition line as below.

```
if ($('.figure').css("left") == "702px") {
```

You should give `!important` while adding `display` `inline-block` to avoid the style being over-ridden.

So your code should look something like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('.figure').css("left")== "702px") {
    $('.level1').css("display", "inline-block !important");
  } else {
    $('.level1').css("display", "none !important");            
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your intended function in vanilla javascript:

```
function checkFigureLeft() {
    var figure = document.getElementsByClassName('figure')[0];
    var level1 = document.getElementsByClassName('level1')[0];
    var figureLeft = window.getComputedStyle(figure).getPropertyValue('left');

    if (figureLeft >= '702px') {
        level1.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } 

    else {
        level1.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, both css is not applying.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example solution

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('div').css('left', '100px');
  
  if($('div').css('left') == '100px'){
    $('span').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  display: none;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<button>Click ME!!!</button>

<span>Clicked ME!!!</span>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @SagarKodte I just kept the button to showcase that animation works & following condition.